# Error in React: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, jsx

I am receiving the Error in React: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render. I checked other posts ,which addressed using conditionals with react hooks, but I am unable to diagnose a similar problem in my code. If I comment out the Object.keys portion of the code in challenges.js, the error does not show, but if I leave it in I get the error. I believe it is being caused by a bug in the keepsessionutils.js file. Please assist.

challenges.js

```
return (
    <div className="about">
      <div className="about-header">
        <div className="about-headerText">
          <h2> Dummy Challenge </h2>
          <h2> Dummy Challenge </h2>
          <h2> Dummy Challenge </h2>
          <h2> Dummy Challenge </h2>
          <h2> Dummy Challenge </h2>
          <hr />
              {Object.keys(valid_playlists).map(key => (
            <button type="button" onClick={createChallengeUtil(key)}>
              {valid_playlists[key]}
            </button>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

createChallengeUtil.js

```
export default function createChallengeUtil(playlist_id) {
  // Check if there are at least 20 songs
  var token = KeepSession();
  // Populate Firebase with challenge data
}
```

keepsession.js

```
export default function KeepSession() {
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState(
    localStorage.getItem('myValueInLocalStorage') || ''
  );
  // Here I am just checking to see if we need to retrieve a new token or not.
   if (value === "undefined"){
    var token = getLocalToken();
   }
   else{
      var token = value;
   }
   // This block detects if the user refreshes the page and stores the current token if so.
    window.onbeforeunload = (e) => {
    // I'm about to refresh! do something...
    localStorage.setItem('myValueInLocalStorage', token)
            setValue(token);
    };
    return token
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a look to [React Hooks rules](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#explanation).

It will be better to apply another approach. Also, as I can see, you are calling KeepSession on each map iteration, but you are not using playlist_id to generate a different hook, so it ends up creating a bunch of hooks with the same name.

Also, at the end, what is the purpose of creating these Hooks inside of your function if you are not using them, nor returning a reference to it from KeepSession()?

Answer (score 0):

As Long your valid_playlists modifies, you will be calling more hooks on line  so when your list changes, will change times you are calling hooks.

React remembers hooks called and the order.

Try to change a little bit your approach. 
- Name `useMyHook` for any non component function using hooks. 
- Do not call function to create listeners `onClick={doSomething()}`
- Do not use hook inside handlers `createChallengeUtil` is callling hooks

https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-react-hook-60960690-63yf2

I hope this this approach is fine for you.

Comment: Thank you for this. I have a quick question. Further up in my challenges function, I need to make use of the token. With your method, how can I achieve this? If I am not wrong, currently the token is abstracted from the challenge file, but this need not be the case.
In your sandbox, that would mean i need the token in the App function component. Thank ypu very much.

Comment: I think I need more info about your scenario. You say you need token info at App level?
If the token is the same for all the application I will use useKeepSesion on App Component
But I think is not the case you need. Can you fork codesandbox and explain what you need?

Comment: No problem, i will do that on sandbox.

Comment: I think a good approach could be "configure your api not at render stage" I've created a hook that configure API reading the token. https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-react-hook-60960690-8s78j